# Apache httpd drops active connection(chunked long polling) behind proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, python-requests, long-polling

We have sync service(10.17.8.89) which syncs the data from the replicator service(10.17.4.184) over HTTP long polling.  Both sync and replicator service is written using python requests lib and eventlet wisgi module.

Replicator service accepts request on port 6601 and is behind Apache httpd. Rewirte rule is used to proxy the request.

**Rewrite rule looks like this**

```
RewriteRule ^/sync.*    http://localhost:6601%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [P]
```

We use chunked encoding to transfer the data. Data is defined as length:data. 
Every 2 seconds heartbeat '1:0' is sent from replicator to sync to keep the connection alive.

Apache timeout is configured to 20 seconds.

**System looks like this**
[image: System looks like this]

Apache drops the connections by sending the FIN packet to both replicator service and sync service at random interval say after 4 minutes and drops the connection even after sending heartbeat every 2 seconds.

**packet capture from client to server**
[image: packet capture from client to server]

**packet capture from server to client**
[image: packet capture from server to client]

**packet capture from apache to replicator service**
[image: packet capture from apache to replicator service]

Can any one help us in resolving the issue of why Apache drops the connection.